# Pressing back button stops and destroys my Activity insted of resuming it

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost, onresume, onpause

I' working on an app with TabGroupActivity. 
I'm launching through a tabhost activies so i can have more than one Intents in each tab:

```
public class MainTabActivity extends TabActivity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tab);
    final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();   
     tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
              .setIndicator("Que")
              .setContent(new Intent(this, TabGroup2Activity.class)));
}
```

TabGroup2Activity class:

```
public class TabGroup2Activity extends TabGroupActivity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),QueActivity.class);
    startChildActivity("categorias", i);
}
```

}

I got the TabGroupActivity from [this](http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) page:

My issue is when i'm clicking on the second tab, i get my QueActivity.class opened. It's basically a listview with items retrieved from a Data Base. When i clic a row i get a new intent opened with information passed by Bundle object. 
The problem is when i hit the back button in this intent, i go back to the QueActivity Intent, which was on onPause() event, but it goes to onStop(), onDestroy() and onStart() event insted going to other state (onResume i think) where there is no need to be created again. The issue is the Intent being created again executes SQL querys and things that i don't need to execute anymore.
I'd like to press the go back and retreive the last intent in a way i don't have to create it again. 
I hope I've explained myself succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have closed the CURSOR off DB in your activity wherever you have used it.

```
stopManagingCursor(c);
```

Comment: I have no Cursors declared. The DB is extern to the APP. I'm using web services, maybe that's why?

Comment: I've no error in logcat, the only issue is when i return to the activitie, it loads again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<activity ... android:launchMode="singleTop" />
```

In your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

This thing is device specific, some devices didnt go to `onresume`, and start `life cycle` from start, To handle that you can use `Savedinstatnce`, to save a state .